# wordpress site domain open the old site domain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, dns

old path

- http://www.tantifilm.top

testing path

- http://www.tantifilm.top/test

i uploaded my complete wordpress project in test folder my new wordpress site path like this when i open this url site opened perfectly

- http://www.tantifilm.top/test/

when i click on any navigation link  page opened and urls show me this

http://www.tantifilm.top/serie-tv/ link
 instead of this http://www.tantifilm.top/test/serie-tv/

```
siteurl   : http://www.tantifilm.top/test/
baseurl   : http://www.tantifilm.top/test/
```

> i import the database and update the link in wp_option i dont understand why  http://www.tantifilm.top/test/serie-tv/ this link not open

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your databse (sql):

```
//SQL to change domain name
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com','http://www.new-domain.com'); 
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com'); 
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com'); 
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

And then go to the WordPress backend, "Settings" -> "Permalinks" and click "Save Changes".

I hope this helps.

Comment: it's not safe to do this with SQL if we don't have enough experience, it's better to use plugin for that

Comment: Not need to use a plugin for everything, in my opinion. I used this code for many sites and I've never have a problem. And he is using a "test" site.

Comment: i know and you are right. But using this code involve knowing how to execute SQL statement in the hosting. It's easy but not for everyone. So the plugin solution will be the suitable for everyone (my opinion too ;) )

Comment: You are right, but I just prefer to use code for this small things. I agree plugins can be easier.

Comment: i just run this query and my whole project style gone

Comment: my project have only url problem and i run this query and everything disapper nothing would be working :(

Comment: styles.css etc show like this http://www.tantifilm.top/test//test/wp-content/themes/smashingMultiMedia/css/print.css

Comment: how i change this url into  http://www.tantifilm.top/test/wp-content/themes/smashingMultiMedia/css/print.css using your query please help me @Aida

Comment: You probably added the new url (or old one) with the ending on "/". Download the database and do a search and replace. Make sure the new url is http://www.tantifilm.top/test and not http://www.tantifilm.top/test/ (ending with /)